# Should the game host be the authority, or another dumb client?

Tags: game-design, networking, multiplayer

When designing a networked multiplayer-game where one player hosts and others connect, there are two strategies I'm aware of:

- **Have the host-player's game be the authority**, with all other players as dumb-clients trying to catch up with the current game-state.  In the code, there will have to be lots of special cases, depending on if the current player is the host or not.
- **Make the host a dumb-client** like everyone else by running a hidden dedicated server on another thread.  The dedicated-server will be the authority, and the host will connect to it like everyone else (through localhost).

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each of these?  Which is used most often (or does it vary by game type/size)?

Comment: The first case you are describing can be one form of P2P networking(with one authoritative client) and its usually much more complex, and harder to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 13):

The dumb-client approach is best from a pure design point of view- it heavily limits the amount of different code you need between host and clients, and allows the server to run asynchronously. The downside is that the host's machine requires extra resources- but I guess it always did.

Answer (score 8):

Between these two options the dumb-client approach is certainly best for the reasons DeadMG mentions.

There is another option which is make every client an authority, it has the advantage of the dumb-client that all peers share the same code. The other advantage is that it might be a lot more fair if you set the right rules because no one has the 0-lag-to-server advantage.

This can ofcourse be rather tricky to implement depending on the game type. Your protocol will have to deal with solving conflicts between peers, probably using some kind of ownership scheme. Leaving only the conflicts where 2 peers claim ownership of the same game object.

Googling Peer-2-Peer multiplayer protocols might give you some more details about this approach.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-can-i-make-a-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game Here's some more info :)

Comment: Interesting.  That post claims that this is how "most strategy titles" implement networking.  Is this really true?  Is this how eg. *Command and Conquer* and *Starcraft* work?

Comment: @BlueRaja, this is how Starcraft works, yes. In Starcraft there is no authority at all. Warcraft III and Starcraft II have more centralised message exchange model, lag and disconnect handling, but fundamentally the same in that each client hosts its own game state.

Comment: The other advantage of this networking model is that it allows to support large consistent shared world state with minimal synchronisation traffic.

Comment: The largest disadvantage of this model is its inherent vulnerability to "maphacking", that is revealing some game state data the player can't normally see.

Comment: I am still vastly confused about how this could possibly work.  For instance, in SC, the units use some criteria to determine whom to attack automatically.  What if on my computer, unit A attacked unit B, but on your computer, unit A attacked unit C, because of some minor discrepancy that occurred for a few frames.  How do we resolve that?  Will Unit B's health go back up on my screen if the game takes your side?

Comment: "minor discrepancies" are not possible because all the calculations are exact and deterministic. All the seemingly random events are pre-determined using the shared initial seed value. This works perfectly well when all the game state calculations are performed with integral numbers (fixed-point included), but may (will?) break with floating point arithmetic because of its potentially non-deterministic imprecision.

Comment: It's like when playing chess players make moves by saying "e2-e4" and everyone knows what the board state is without having to communicate it.

Comment: Er, floating-point imprecision is deterministic.  But more to the point, "minor discrepancies" certainly can happen when timing is important:  imagine in starcraft that I attack-move a unit towards two other units - he will pick whichever unit he sees first, and shoot it until it dies.  If my unit attacks the first unit on my screen, but the second unit on his screen (perhaps because he told it to move closer at the last second, and I didn't receive the packet in time), then suddenly we both see a different unit dying, a *major* discrepancy!  How do we decide whose state is correct?

Comment: All the game state computations happen only when all the relevant packets are known to have arrived. In your example, your unit will not pick a target until all the orders of the enemy units are already known. And if they are known, then the target can be picked identically on every computer. Obviously, instantly knowing the enemy commands is impossible. That's why the game simulation lags behind the player input. The commands you give are scheduled to happen several frames later and this margin is usually enough to distribute the commands to all the players. If not, the game stops and waits.