# Networking in real-time strategy games

Tags: algorithm, networking, strategy

What is the current state-of-the-art to network real-time strategy games?

I seem to recall that a few years ago, some AAA titles only transmitted the player inputs (Starcraft 1, Age of Empires). Since this requires you to keep everything else totally deterministic, is this still a viable option? Synchronizing random number generators seems feasible, but what about subtle differences in FPU implementations etc..?

Or are strategy games using something closer to action-game networking, where individual entities are transmitted instead (with some form of prediction and (delta) compression)?

If so, how are volatile items like projectiles treated?

What about client/server versus peer-to-peer? I'm guessing that all this is strongly interrelated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Duplicate of [RTS Game Protocol](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15192) - yes this is still how it's done.  As for differing FPU implementations, see [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14776) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php 
This is still how networking is done in RTS games. P2P is also the normal way of handling connections. 
Using a lock timestep model however results in the irritating case of desync and cheating handling. There is good way of recovering when a desync happens and all RTS games simply says "Quit the match". Bug tracing desync errors is also a nightmare.

Comment: Another good article on locked timestep network games: http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/09/synchronous-rts-engines-and-a-tale-of-desyncs/

Answer (score 2):

This is a great read, and will answer a lot of your questions:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/NetworkingOverview.html

In my strategy/tower defence game, I am using a client/server model and am able to keep everything deterministic so far. The client only sends the server requests to do stuff (but doesn't ever actually **do** anything), and the server sends updates, creations, and deletions down to the clients when things change. Even though my game is currently deterministic, I never trust my clients to do anything right, the server is the boss and has full control over the game. The client is just a dumb terminal.

To make everything really simple, I am using a combination of Reflection and Eventing to keep my entities completely in the dark about the networking side of things. I also use the concept of an Actor and a "Force" (as opposed to an Actor and Pawn in an FPS like Unreal). This allows for really nice encapsulation and a place to store the Force's money and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Not for RTS but any fast-paced game will need interpolation & prediction

http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking