# Is there a library or a framework that handles networking in an RTS?

Tags: networking, rts

I'm aiming for making a(n) RTS game with networking so instead of doing tedious stuff like networking I wonder if there is a library/framework that will save me the effort. I intend to make that game in Unity if it is of any interest.

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/rts-game-protocol

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you will find a specialized RTS network library. You can find an open source RTS engine, such as [OpenRTS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arrakis/), or a general purpose network library, like the ones Valmond recommended.

If you will not use an RTS engine, then I recommend reading this awesome series of posts on how to design your network layer: [Synchronous RTS Engine and a tale of desyncs](http://web.archive.org/web/20140719071558/http://www.altdev.co/2011/07/09/synchronous-rts-engines-and-a-tale-of-desyncs/). Or the Gamasutra article [1500 Archers on a 28.8: Network Programming in Age of Empires and Beyond](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php)

Comment: The _Synchronous RTS Engine_ article now 404s. [Here's a permanent link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140719071558/http://www.altdev.co/2011/07/09/synchronous-rts-engines-and-a-tale-of-desyncs/).

Comment: Thanks, updated the link. Wait..... AltDevBlog is dead?? :( Not that I'm really surprised tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Raknet, it is not a RTS-specialized library but a quite good one.

Boost::Asio is "better" but less a library 'for games', you might want to check out what it offers though.

Usually you use a lockstep approach for RTS games and I know of no 'open' libraries handling those (you might want to search for it though).

Worst case, you can make a game running on a LAN (no latency etc) and move further later (as long as you have a fully functionnal multiplayer game up and running, switching from LAN to say the internet should be quite possible).

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post about a lockstep implementation in Unity3D. You can view it at:
http://clintonbrennan.com/2013/12/lockstep-implementation-in-unity3d/