# Is It Possible To Make Matchmaking System Without Server?

Tags: multiplayer, matchmaking

I want to make a matchmaking system without a server, but I don't know much about matchmaking. First, let me list what I want to do:

- Cheating is not important in the game, so that the architecture will be listen-server. (One of the clients in the lobby will be host.)
- The players will be connected to each other by sending invitations. I will not list any lobbies in the game.
- All the data in the game will be sent via RPC functions. (I have already coded this.)

The game will be published on mobile platforms. I wonder if I can connect 2 players to each other in the game without a server. Is that possible? Can I make this kind of system by using a library like socket.io?

Comment: [This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-can-i-make-a-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you.